How can I create a loading state for the client navigation in NextJS (with app router) and keep SSR
I work on creating new next.js app with app router.
I created a page.js which is a server component that fetches a list of products based on the query param and renders the list. I also have a filter component rendered which is a select element which changes the query param. I want to display a loading state while the new data based one the query param is being fetched. But I still want to have SSR if the user goes directly to that page.
page.ts
export default async function Listing({
  searchParams,
}: {
  params: { slug: string };
  searchParams: Record<string, string | string[] | undefined>;
}) {
  const products = await api.product.listing(Number(searchParams.colorId ?? 1));

  return (
    <div>
      <ColorFilter />
      {products.slice(0, 10).map((product) => (
        <Item key={product.id} product={product} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

ColorFilter.ts
export function ColorFilter() {
  const router = useRouter();
  return (
    <select
      onChange={(e) => {
        router.push(`/listing?colorId=${e.target.value}`);
      }}
    >
      <option value="1">Black</option>
      <option value="2">Brown</option>
      <option value="3">Yellow</option>
      <option value="4">Blue</option>
    </select>
  );
}

I thought that adding a loading.ts file will help with that but I'm loosing SSR when I add it. How can I have SSR working and loading state on client-side navigation?

It looks like the commerce example nextjs app has the same issue: Try: https://demo.vercel.store/search/headwear when changing sorting you don't see any feedback (no loading indicator). Use network throttling slow 3G to notice the issue. The source code is here: https://github.com/vercel/commerce/tree/main
